# Report Design Templates

Tags: reporting, devexpress, look-and-feel, xtrareport

We are using DevExpress XtraReports 2009v3.3 and although I can achieve what I want through various formatting objects in code, there must be a (better/less painless/maintainable/visual) way of achieving what I require...

I need to produce a report, designed to end-user 'look & feel'. We have many companies which use our software and they all require different design schema's/templates for their reports. For example - a single report, depending on who logs on (we know what company they belong to) apply the template the report should use.

As an example, some of the requirements (per end-user/company) include:

their own logo (positioned in the correct place),
Margins being of specific size
their own fonts (or font choice)
alternating colours schemes
Specific rows / columns being particular colours (both permanently and based on value)
Formatting of values, for example a european user would get euro, a uk user gets pounds on certain columns/cells/rows.

I know there is an End-User Report Designer, however this isn't what we require - I must create the schema/template design for a report then apply it at runtime.

Also using save/load layout for multiple repx files isn't the best solution as a change to the report would cause a lot of extra work as you would have to update each repx template file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create different reports and save it to the repx format via [XtraReport.SaveLayout](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReport_SaveLayouttopic142) method and use these [repx files as template](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument2592).

[Similar but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222197/how-can-i-serialize-a-devexpress-xtrareport-report-design)

I [asked dev express](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q291406.aspx) and they basically said there isn't any 'layout abstraction' that would do what I require.